# Postgres hstore update all without deleting existing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, update-all

I've started working with rails 4.1.5 and postgresql 9.3.5, so my question is how to use update_all with hstore in postgress in this situation(if that's even possible):
"1" => [1, 2, 3]
so if "1" exists, add number to array, else create new hstore entry.

This is what I've been trying, but it doesn't work.

```
Account.update_all("column = hstore('1', array_append(avals(slice(column, '1')), '2'))")
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a terribly useful description of the failure...